# How can I select the substring represented by the original string except the two initial characters?

Tags: java, string, substring

I know that in Java I can extract a substring from a String object doing something like:

```
String string= "Hello World";
String subString = string.substring(5);
```

And in this wat the **subString** variable will contain only the **Hello** string

and I know that I can also specify 2 index to select a substring, something like:

```
String subString = string.substring(6, 11);
```

That will select the **World** string.

But what can I do if, given a string, I want select the substring represented by the original string except the two initial characters.

So for example I have:

```
String value = "12345"
```

and my substring have to be **345**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String subString = string.substring(5);` doesn't do what you think it does.

Actually `string.substring(2)` returns a String containing all the characters of the first String except the first two characters.

When you want a sub string starting at the beginning of the input String, you use the two parameters version - for example `string.substring(0,5)` for the first 5 characters.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29),

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the
>   end of this string.
>
> Examples:
>
> "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
>
> "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
>
> "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)
>
> Parameters: beginIndex the beginning index, inclusive. Returns: the
>   specified substring. Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex
>   is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sb = "12345";
        String s = sb.substring(2);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**output**

```
345
```